# CryptoJS -- `toString` method crash

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I use CryptoJS to do some AES encryption. And the code is

```
const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key)
```

If I use `cipher.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)`, then the web crushes, and says "TypeError: wordArray.clamp is not a function". It seems that only `toString()` without any parameters can work for me, so I want to know the default encoder for `toString()` method for decrypting in backend.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

The following code returns a WordArray and not a string, so the code crashes because a need a string:

```
const hashcode = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(a.result));
```

To solve it with toString() methods, just add it in the end.

```
const hashcode = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(a.result)).toString();
```